# How to avoid multiple finds of same document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose so please forgive me if this sounds stupid.

For every edit, I want to store the historic values and also modify the existing value of my collection. 
So here's the code

```
 collection.findById(type_id).select({ "history": 0 })


 .then(function(data){

   var changes =  { data : data, by : user_id }
  return  collection.findOneAndUpdateAsync({_id:type_id}, 
            {$push: {"history": changes }}) 
     })


  .then(function(data){
 return  collection.findOneAndUpdateAsync({_id:type_id}, info) 
})


   .then(function(res){

  resolve(res) })
```

This piece of code works just fine, but I don't want to do multiple find for the same collection. 
Would be great if you can suggest something better and efficient.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think all that's possible within an atomic update. The best you can do is reduce the number of calls to the server down to two: your first call is the update using **[`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** with the `new` option set to false (default), this will allow you to access
the data before the update. You can then use the second call to update history with this data. For example:

```
collection.findByIdAndUpdateAsync(type_id, info /*, { "new": false } */)
     .then(function(data){
        var changes =  { 
            "data": data, 
            "by": user_id 
        };
        return  collection.findByIdAndUpdateAsync(
            type_id, 
            { "$push": { "history": changes } },
            { "new": true }
        ); 
    })
    .then(function(res){  resolve(res) });
```